# Setting up SonarQube on Centos 7 with mysql 5.5 (mariadb): Failed to start SonarQube

Tags: mysql, jdbc, sonarqube, mariadb, centos7

I am attempting to set up an instance of SonarQube on my laptop with CentOS 7. I have been following rigorously the instructions provided on their website (http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Installing). Just to be clear with what I did, I will include each step(though the problem very likely is in step 4):

1. Verified versions of MySQL (5.5 uses InnoDB) and Java (jre 1.7)
2. Created database and user like they suggest: https://github.com/SonarSource/sonar-examples/blob/master/scripts/database/mysql/create_database.sql
3. Installed (unzipped) package in my `/srv` directory
4. Uncommented/edited the following lines in `<installation>/conf/sonar.properties` to be (exactly):

   ```
   sonar.jdbc.username=sonarqube              
   sonar.jdbc.password=mypassword          
   sonar.jdbc.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost/sonarqube
   ```

I admit that I have never used the JDBC and so I'm not sure what username/password I should put (if any?). And is their more setup to get the JDBC to work?

5. Ran the command `<installation>/bin/linux-x86-64/sonar.sh start` which spit out:

   Failed to start SonarQube.

I was trying to include all the log contents (from /logs/sonar.log) that was generated between the time it starts and dies (about 10 seconds). I had to cut out quite a bit, but all the first errors are here.

```
--> Wrapper Started as Daemon
Launching a JVM...
Wrapper (Version 3.2.3) http://wrapper.tanukisoftware.org
  Copyright 1999-2006 Tanuki Software, Inc.  All Rights Reserved.

...
:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=75 -XX:+UseCMSInitiatingOccupancyOnly -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Djava.io.tmpdir=/srv/sonarqube-4.5.1/temp -cp ./lib/common/*:./lib/search/* org.sonar.search.SearchServer /tmp/sq-process333134131230919159properties
2014.12.09 13:40:03 WARN  sea[o.s.p.ProcessEntryPoint]  Starting search
2014.12.09 13:40:03 INFO  sea[o.s.s.SearchServer]  Starting ES[sonarqube] on port: 9001
2014.12.09 13:40:03 INFO  sea[o.elasticsearch.node]  [sonar-1418157602647] version[1.1.2], pid[20672], build[e511f7b/2014-05-22T12:27:39Z]
...
-XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Djava.io.tmpdir=/srv/sonarqube-4.5.1/temp -cp ./lib/common/*:./lib/server/*:/srv/sonarqube-4.5.1/lib/jdbc/mysql/mysql-connector-java-5.1.27.jar org.sonar.server.app.WebServer /tmp/sq-process3241783411099648345properties
2014.12.09 13:40:08 WARN  web[o.s.p.ProcessEntryPoint]  Starting web
2014.12.09 13:40:08 INFO  web[o.s.s.app.Connectors]  HTTP connector is enabled on port 9000
2014.12.09 13:40:08 INFO  web[o.s.s.app.Webapp]  Webapp directory: /srv/sonarqube-4.5.1/web
2014.12.09 13:40:08 INFO  web[o.e.plugins]  [sonar-1418157602647] loaded [], sites []
2014.12.09 13:40:09 INFO  web[o.s.s.p.ServerImpl]  SonarQube Server / 4.5.1 / 0c5e3bad51d43c05de47187d16831067bea16a3f
2014.12.09 13:40:09 INFO  web[o.s.c.p.Database]  Create JDBC datasource for jdbc:mysql://localhost/sonarqube?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=utf8
2014.12.09 13:40:09 ERROR web[o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/]]  Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.sonar.server.platform.PlatformServletContextListener
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can not connect to database. Please check connectivity and settings (see the properties prefixed by 'sonar.jdbc.').
    at org.sonar.core.persistence.DefaultDatabase.checkConnection(DefaultDatabase.java:115) ~[sonar-core-4.5.1.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.core.persistence.DefaultDatabase.start(DefaultDatabase.java:73) ~[sonar-core-4.5.1.jar:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.7.0_71]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57) ~[na:1.7.0_71]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.7.0_71]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606) ~[na:1.7.0_71]
    at org.picocontainer.lifecycle.ReflectionLifecycleStrategy.invokeMethod(ReflectionLifecycleStrategy.java:110) ~[picocontainer-2.14.3.jar:na]
    at org.picocontainer.lifecycle.ReflectionLifecycleStrategy.start(ReflectionLifecycleStrategy.java:89) ~[picocontainer-2.14.3.jar:na]
    at org.picocontainer.injectors.AbstractInjectionFactory$LifecycleAdapter.start(AbstractInjectionFactory.java:84) ~[picocontainer-2.14.3.jar:na]
    at org.picocontainer.behaviors.AbstractBehavior.start(AbstractBehavior.java:169) ~[picocontainer-2.14.3.jar:na]
    at org.picocontainer.behaviors.Stored$RealComponentLifecycle.start(Stored.java:132) ~[picocontainer-2.14.3.jar:na]
    at org.picocontainer.behaviors.Stored.start(Stored.java:110) ~[picocontainer-2.14.3.jar:na]
    at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.potentiallyStartAdapter(DefaultPicoContainer.java:1015) ~[picocontainer-2.14.3.jar:na]
    at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.startAdapters(DefaultPicoContainer.java:1008) ~[picocontainer-2.14.3.jar:na]
    at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.start(DefaultPicoContainer.java:766) ~[picocontainer-2.14.3.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.api.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:91) ~[sonar-plugin-api-4.5.1.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.server.platform.Platform.startLevel1Container(Platform.java:96) ~[sonar-server-4.5.1.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.server.platform.Platform.init(Platform.java:72) ~[sonar-server-4.5.1.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.server.platform.PlatformServletContextListener.contextInitialized(PlatformServletContextListener.java:42) ~[sonar-server-4.5.1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4973) [tomcat-embed-core-7.0.54.jar:7.0.54]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5467) [tomcat-embed-core-7.0.54.jar:7.0.54]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150) [tomcat-embed-core-7.0.54.jar:7.0.54]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559) [tomcat-embed-core-7.0.54.jar:7.0.54]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549) [tomcat-embed-core-7.0.54.jar:7.0.54]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262) [na:1.7.0_71]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [na:1.7.0_71]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [na:1.7.0_71]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.7.0_71]
Caused by: org.apache.commons.dbcp.SQLNestedException: Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (Access denied for user 'sonar'@'localhost' to database 'sonarqube')
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.createPoolableConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:1549) ~[commons-dbcp-1.4.jar:1.4]
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.createDataSource(BasicDataSource.java:1388) ~[commons-dbcp-1.4.jar:1.4]
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.getConnection(BasicDataSource.java:1044) ~[commons-dbcp-1.4.jar:1.4]
    at org.sonar.core.persistence.DefaultDatabase.checkConnection(DefaultDatabase.java:113) ~[sonar-core-4.5.1.jar:na]
    ... 27 common frames omitted
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Access denied for user 'sonar'@'localhost' to database 'sonarqube'
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[na:1.7.0_71]
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57) ~[na:1.7.0_71]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) ~[na:1.7.0_71]
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526) ~[na:1.7.0_71]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:411) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.27.jar:na]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:386) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.27.jar:na]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1054) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.27.jar:na]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4237) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.27.jar:na]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4169) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.27.jar:na]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:928) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.27.jar:na]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.proceedHandshakeWithPluggableAuthentication(MysqlIO.java:1750) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.27.jar:na]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.doHandshake(MysqlIO.java:1290) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.27.jar:na]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.coreConnect(ConnectionImpl.java:2493) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.27.jar:na]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:2526) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.27.jar:na]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:2311) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.27.jar:na]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:834) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.27.jar:na]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection.<init>(JDBC4Connection.java:47) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.27.jar:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[na:1.7.0_71]
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57) ~[na:1.7.0_71]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) ~[na:1.7.0_71]
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526) ~[na:1.7.0_71]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:411) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.27.jar:na]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:416) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.27.jar:na]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:347) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.27.jar:na]
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DriverConnectionFactory.createConnection(DriverConnectionFactory.java:38) ~[commons-dbcp-1.4.jar:1.4]
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.PoolableConnectionFactory.makeObject(PoolableConnectionFactory.java:582) ~[commons-dbcp-1.4.jar:1.4]
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.validateConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:1556) ~[commons-dbcp-1.4.jar:1.4]
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.createPoolableConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:1545) ~[commons-dbcp-1.4.jar:1.4]
    ... 30 common frames omitted
2014.12.09 13:40:09 INFO  web[jruby.rack]  jruby 1.7.9 (ruby-1.8.7p370) 2013-12-06 87b108a on OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM 1.7.0_71-mockbuild_2014_10_15_10_02-b00 [linux-amd64]
2014.12.09 13:40:09 INFO  web[jruby.rack]  using a shared (threadsafe!) runtime
2014.12.09 13:40:12 ERROR web[jruby.rack]  initialization failed
org.jruby.rack.RackInitializationException: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.jruby.rack.RackInitializationException.wrap(RackInitializationException.java:31) ~[jruby-rack-1.1.13.2.jar:na]
    at org.jruby.rack.RackApplicationFactoryDecorator.init(RackApplicationFactoryDecorator.java:98) ~[jruby-rack-1.1.13.2.jar:na]
    at org.jruby.rack.RackServletContextListener.contextInitialized(RackServletContextListener.java:50) ~[jruby-rack-1.1.13.2.jar:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4973) [tomcat-embed-core-7.0.54.jar:7.0.54]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5467) [tomcat-embed-core-7.0.54.jar:7.0.54]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150) [tomcat-embed-core-7.0.54.jar:7.0.54]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559) [tomcat-embed-core-7.0.54.jar:7.0.54]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549) [tomcat-embed-core-7.0.54.jar:7.0.54]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262) [na:1.7.0_71]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [na:1.7.0_71]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [na:1.7.0_71]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.7.0_71]
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at org.sonar.server.ui.JRubyFacade.get(JRubyFacade.java:84) ~[sonar-server-4.5.1.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.server.ui.JRubyFacade.getDatabase(JRubyFacade.java:238) ~[sonar-server-4.5.1.jar:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.7.0_71]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57) ~[na:1.7.0_71]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.7.0_71]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606) ~[na:1.7.0_71]
    at org.jruby.javasupport.JavaMethod.invokeDirectWithExceptionHandling(JavaMethod.java:440) ~[jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
    at org.jruby.javasupport.JavaMethod.invokeDirect(JavaMethod.java:304) ~[jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
    at org.jruby.java.invokers.InstanceMethodInvoker.call(InstanceMethodInvoker.java:52) ~[jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
    at org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.cacheAndCall(CachingCallSite.java:306) ~[jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
    at org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.call(CachingCallSite.java:136) ~[jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
    at org.jruby.ast.CallNoArgNode.interpret(CallNoArgNode.java:60) ~[jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
    at org.jruby.ast.CallNoArgNode.interpret(CallNoArgNode.java:60) ~[jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
    at org.jruby.ast.CallNoArgNode.interpret(CallNoArgNode.java:60) ~[jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
    at org.jruby.ast.NewlineNode.interpret(NewlineNode.java:105) ~[jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
    at org.jruby.ast.CallNoArgNode.interpret(CallNoArgNode.java:60) ~[jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
    at org.jruby.ast.CallOneArgNode.interpret(CallOneArgNode.java:57) ~[jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
    at org.jruby.ast.NewlineNode.interpret(NewlineNode.java:105) ~[jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
    at org.jruby.ast.BlockNode.interpret(BlockNode.java:71) ~[jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
    at org.jruby.ast.RootNode.interpret(RootNode.java:129) ~[jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
    at org.jruby.evaluator.ASTInterpreter.INTERPRET_EVAL(ASTInterpreter.java:95) ~[jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
    at org.jruby.evaluator.ASTInterpreter.evalWithBinding(ASTInterpreter.java:184) ~[jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
    at org.jruby.RubyKernel.evalCommon(RubyKernel.java:1156) ~[jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
    at org.jruby.RubyKernel.eval(RubyKernel.java:1114) ~[jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
    at org.jruby.RubyKernel$INVOKER$s$0$3$eval.call(RubyKernel$INVOKER$s$0$3$eval.gen) ~[jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
    at org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.DynamicMethod.call(DynamicMethod.java:180) ~[jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
    at org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.cacheAndCall(CachingCallSite.java:296) ~[jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
    at org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.call(CachingCallSite.java:72) ~[jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
    at org.jruby.ast.FCallManyArgsNode.interpret(FCallManyArgsNode.java:60) ~[jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
    at org.jruby.ast.NewlineNode.interpret(NewlineNode.java:105) ~[jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
    at org.jruby.ast.IfNode.interpret(IfNode.java:118) ~[jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
    at org.jruby.ast.NewlineNode.interpret(NewlineNode.java:105) ~[jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
    at org.jruby.evaluator.ASTInterpreter.INTERPRET_METHOD(ASTInterpreter.java:74) ~[jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
    at org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.InterpretedMethod.call(InterpretedMethod.java:139) ~[jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
    at org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.DefaultMethod.call(DefaultMethod.java:182) ~[jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
    at org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.cacheAndCall(CachingCallSite.java:306) ~[jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
    at org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.call(CachingCallSite.java:136) ~[jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
    at org.jruby.ast.CallNoArgNode.interpret(CallNoArgNode.java:60) ~[jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
    at org.jruby.ast.CallOneArgNode.interpret(CallOneArgNode.java:57) ~[jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
    at org.jruby.ast.NewlineNode.interpret(NewlineNode.java:105) ~[jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
    at org.jruby.ast.BlockNode.interpret(BlockNode.java:71) ~[jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
    at org.jruby.evaluator.ASTInterpreter.INTERPRET_METHOD(ASTInterpreter.java:74) ~[jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
    at org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.InterpretedMethod.call(InterpretedMethod.java:139) ~[jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
    at org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.DefaultMethod.call(DefaultMethod.java:182) ~[jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
    at org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.cacheAndCall(CachingCallSite.java:306) ~[jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
    at org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.call(CachingCallSite.java:136) ~[jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
    at org.jruby.ast.CallNoArgNode.interpret(CallNoArgNode.java:60) ~[jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
    at org.jruby.ast.AttrAssignOneArgNode.interpret(AttrAssignOneArgNode.java:33) ~[jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
    at org.jruby.ast.NewlineNode.interpret(NewlineNode.java:105) ~[jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
    at org.jruby.ast.BlockNode.interpret(BlockNode.java:71) ~[jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
    at org.jruby.ast.IfNode.interpret(IfNode.java:116) ~[jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
    at org.jruby.ast.NewlineNode.interpret(NewlineNode.java:105) ~[jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
    at org.jruby.evaluator.ASTInterpreter.INTERPRET_METHOD(ASTInterpreter.java:74) ~[jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
    at org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.InterpretedMethod.call(InterpretedMethod.java:139) ~[jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
    at org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.DefaultMethod.call(DefaultMethod.java:182) ~[jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
    at org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.cacheAndCall(CachingCallSite.java:306) ~[jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
    at org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.call(CachingCallSite.java:136) ~[jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
    at org.jruby.ast.VCallNode.interpret(VCallNode.java:88) ~[jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
    at org.jruby.ast.NewlineNode.interpret(NewlineNode.java:105) ~[jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
    at org.jruby.ast.BlockNode.interpret(BlockNode.java:71) ~[jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
    at org.jruby.evaluator.ASTInterpreter.INTERPRET_METHOD(ASTInterpreter.java:74) ~[jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
    at org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.InterpretedMethod.call(InterpretedMethod.java:161) ~[jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
    at org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.DefaultMethod.call(DefaultMethod.java:190) ~[jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
    at org.jruby.RubyClass.finvoke(RubyClass.java:527) ~[jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
    at org.jruby.RubyBasicObject.send(RubyBasicObject.java:2590) ~[jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
    at org.jruby.RubyKernel.send(RubyKernel.java:2223) ~[jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
    at org.jruby.RubyKernel$INVOKER$s$send.call(RubyKernel$INVOKER$s$send.gen) ~[jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
    at org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.JavaMethod$JavaMethodOneOrNBlock.call(JavaMethod.java:350) ~[jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
    at org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.cacheAndCall(CachingCallSite.java:326) ~[jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
    at org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.call(CachingCallSite.java:170) ~[jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
    at org.jruby.ast.CallOneArgNode.interpret(CallOneArgNode.java:57) ~[jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
    at org.jruby.ast.NewlineNode.interpret(NewlineNode.java:105) ~[jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
    at org.jruby.ast.BlockNode.interpret(BlockNode.java:71) ~[jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
    at org.jruby.evaluator.ASTInterpreter.INTERPRET_METHOD(ASTInterpreter.java:74) ~[jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
    at org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.InterpretedMethod.call(InterpretedMethod.java:161) ~[jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
    at org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.DefaultMethod.call(DefaultMethod.java:190) ~[jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
    at org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.cacheAndCall(CachingCallSite.java:316) ~[jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
    at org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.callBlock(CachingCallSite.java:145) ~[jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
    at org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.callIter(CachingCallSite.java:154) ~[jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
    at org.jruby.ast.CallNoArgBlockNode.interpret(CallNoArgBlockNode.java:64) ~[jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
    at org.jruby.ast.NewlineNode.interpret(NewlineNode.java:105) ~[jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
    at org.jruby.ast.BlockNode.interpret(BlockNode.java:71) ~[jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
    at org.jruby.ast.RootNode.interpret(RootNode.java:129) ~[jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
    at org.jruby.evaluator.ASTInterpreter.INTERPRET_ROOT(ASTInterpreter.java:121) ~[jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
    at org.jruby.Ruby.runInterpreter(Ruby.java:838) ~[jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
    at org.jruby.Ruby.loadFile(Ruby.java:2727) ~[jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
    at org.jruby.runtime.load.ExternalScript.load(ExternalScript.java:66) ~[jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
    at org.jruby.runtime.load.LoadService.load(LoadService.java:359) ~[jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
    at org.jruby.RubyKernel.loadCommon(RubyKernel.java:1107) ~[jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
    at org.jruby.RubyKernel.load(RubyKernel.java:1094) ~[jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
    at org.jruby.RubyKernel$INVOKER$s$0$1$load.call(RubyKernel$INVOKER$s$0$1$load.gen) ~[jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
    at org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.DynamicMethod.call(DynamicMethod.java:210) ~[jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
    at org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.DynamicMethod.call(DynamicMethod.java:206) ~[jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
    at org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.cacheAndCall(CachingCallSite.java:326) ~[jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
    at org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.call(CachingCallSite.java:170) ~[jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
    at org.jruby.ast.FCallOneArgNode.interpret(FCallOneArgNode.java:36) ~[jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
    at org.jruby.ast.NewlineNode.interpret(NewlineNode.java:105) ~[jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
    at org.jruby.ast.BlockNode.interpret(BlockNode.java:71) ~[jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
    at org.jruby.evaluator.ASTInterpreter.INTERPRET_METHOD(ASTInterpreter.java:74) ~[jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
    at org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.InterpretedMethod.call(InterpretedMethod.java:139) ~[jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
    at org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.DefaultMethod.call(DefaultMethod.java:182) ~[jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
    at org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.cacheAndCall(CachingCallSite.java:306) ~[jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
    at org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.call(CachingCallSite.java:136) ~[jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
    at org.jruby.ast.CallNoArgNode.interpret(CallNoArgNode.java:60) ~[jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
    at org.jruby.ast.NewlineNode.interpret(NewlineNode.java:105) ~[jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
    at org.jruby.evaluator.ASTInterpreter.INTERPRET_METHOD(ASTInterpreter.java:74) ~[jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
    at org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.InterpretedMethod.call(InterpretedMethod.java:139) ~[jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
    at org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.DefaultMethod.call(DefaultMethod.java:182) ~[jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
    at org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.cacheAndCall(CachingCallSite.java:306) ~[jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
...
<-- Wrapper Stopped
```

Comment: Can you edit a sample of the logs into your question? It's not considered ideal here to refer to people to a social networking page to fetch them. If there are a lot of them, add 20 lines or so in the question, and put the full set on a pasteboard (e.g. pastie.org) and add that to the comments.

Comment: Sure thing. I wasn't quite sure the right thing to do in this case.

Comment: The error "Can not connect to database. Please check connectivity and settings" looks to be the most pertinent. Have you tried connecting via a JDBC system that you know to work? E.g. the database console in NetBeans? Have you actually created an account and a database in MySQL for this?

Comment: I'm afraid I haven't. Unfortunately, I haven't used JDBC even in testing, but I can definitely give that a whirl in netbeans. I did create a DB and an account in my instance of mysql. Thank you, halfer.

Comment: The more specific error is _"Access denied for user 'sonar'@'localhost' to database 'sonarqube'"_. In other words your database user has insufficient rights to access the database sonarqube. The problem has nothing to do with JDBC.

Comment: Hey Mark, thank you for your comment. Do you have any suggestions as to how to give more permissions to my db user? I'm sorry, this is a very basic question, but I am a novice.

Comment: So it works now and it turns out that my issue was I had the wrong port for mysql set (actually it wasn't even set). Thank you for the help

Comment: can you connect to the database using a tool like dbvisualizer? If so, do you have selinux active? (check the value of `sestatus` on the command line)

Answer (score 1):

I encountered a similar situation. My solution is to set password for mysql.

For example

```
sonar.jdbc.username = sonar  
sonar.jdbc.password = sonar
```

Comment: when sonar connect to mysql with empty password ,an connect exception will be thrown when sonar create its tables in mysql database at first time .